# Yet Another Trigonometric Proof of the Pythagorean Theorem

Tags: solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

Let $\triangle{ABC}$ be a right-triangle with $BC=a$, $AC=b$, $AB=c$ and $\angle{ACB}=\gamma=90^\circ$. Also, let $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$. In the following link https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2020/12/the-pythagorean-theorem-from.html I argue that the expression

$$\cos^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}=\frac{s(s-c)}{ab}=\frac{(a+b)^2-c^2}{4ab}=\frac{1}{2}\tag{1}$$

can be stated without risk of *petitio principii*, from which we have
$$\begin{align*}(a+b)^2-c^2&=2ab\\a^2+2ab+b^2-c^2&=2ab\\a^2+b^2-c^2&=0\end{align*}$$

Is this proof correct? If so, is it new?

Comment: When $\gamma$ is the triangle's right angle, $s-c$ is the radius of the incircle (say, $r$). So your starting formula is effectively the basic observation $$rs=\frac12ab\quad(=|\triangle ABC|)$$ Involving the cosine is unnecessary. (BTW: The link to your proof of the formula is broken.)

Comment: @Blue The link worked for me

Comment: @Blue, Yes, but what I want to show is that the Pythagorean Theorem is just a corollary of $\cos^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}=\frac{s(s-c)}{ab}$ as it is for Ptolomy's Theorem. There is not need of Ptolomy's Theorem to prove the Pythagorean Theorem but it shows how powerfull the Ptolomy's Theorem is. This is the link: https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2020/12/the-pythagorean-theorem-from.html

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed it.

Comment: Blue refers to this link: https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2020/06/another-proof-for-two-well-known.html

Comment: @Blue Now I see and there are three broken links on the blog page.

Comment: No!  Trigonometric proofs of the Pythagorean Theorem do not exist because they are ultimately based on the identity $cos^2 x +\sin^2x=1$, which requires precious proof of the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: @Deltaspace sorry, I have fixed them all.

Comment: @OscarLanzi you have to read this article: http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2009volume9/FG200925index.html

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía: Ah, your blog post makes it clearer that you're using $\cos^2(\gamma/2)$ as a *bridge*, observing its equality to $s(s-c)/ab$ and $1/2$ (for $\gamma=90^\circ$) independently. That's fine. However, since you're using $rs=|\triangle ABC|$ formula to *establish* $\cos^2(\gamma/2)=s(s-c)/ab$, starting with the trig step here still doesn't sit right with me.

Comment: Even when the expression can be reduced to $rs=\frac{ab}{2}$ I never used area's arguments or the radius in my final step.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: To the extent that trig functions merely serve as names for ratios in a right triangle, their use is not dependent upon the Pythagorean Theorem. Of course, some vigilance is needed to ensure that a purported "trigonometric proof" isn't inadvertently slipping-in an appeal to $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, but it's certainly possible to construct proofs that don't make this error.

Comment: @Blue, I have never used the fact $\Delta=rs$ or $\Delta=\frac{ab}{2}$ in my final step. I see not circular argument here. I do not get your objection.

Comment: When I read this article I see a proof of the Pythagorean Theorem in disguise.  You can render the sides of $\triangle OBD$ as $a,b,c$ with $c$ as the hypoteneuse, and when you carry through the calculations shown you will get $a^2+b^2=c^2$ in place of $\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha=1$, meaning the latter is a special case of the former.

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía: In [your proof of the $\cos^2(\gamma/2)=s(s-c)/ab$](https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2020/06/another-proof-for-two-well-known.html), you note "We know $\Delta=rs$ and $\Delta=\frac12ab\sin\gamma$ ..." (with the latter reducing to $\Delta=\frac12ab$ for the right triangle). So, you are implicitly using $rs=\frac12ab$ here. ... I'm not saying your argument is circular; I'm saying it adds unnecessary steps. $rs=\frac12ab$ already leads to $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Now, establishing $\cos^2(\gamma/2)=s(s-c)/ab$ independently of the area relation would make this interesting.

Comment: @Blue, I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Regarding proving the relation w/o areas ... Write $a=b\cos C+c\cos B$, $b=c\cos A+a\cos C$, $c=a\cos B+b\cos A$ (w/ cos merely abbreviating a ratio), and solve this linear system for $\cos A$, $\cos B$, $\cos C$ to get, eg, $\cos C=(a^2+b^2-c^2)/2ab$; thus, the Law of Cosines doesn't require Pythagoras. Moreover, w/o Pythagoras, we can show $$\cos^2(C/2)=(1+\cos C)/2=(a+b+c)(a+b-c)/4ab=s(s-c)/ab$$ Of course, going *from here* to Pythagoras again makes for unnecessary steps, since LoC already gets us there. I'm merely offering an area-(and Pythagoras-)free derivation of the half-angle formula.

Comment: @Blue, thank you for taking the time to answer my questions. 
Some results are considered to be interesting and useful because we can derive a 
good number of other well-known results from them.  The Semiperimeter-Half-Angle Formulas 
seem to be as central as the Pythagorean Thm or the LoC (but not as well-known)...

Comment: In the blog post there is a 
link with a good number of well-known results associated to a triangle that have been proven using the SHA Formulas. When generalized it can be used to prove the Brahmagupta's formula, the Bretschneider's formula, the formula for the area of a bicentric quadrilateral and so on...

Comment: I want to incorporate the Pythagorean thm to the list. Now, I agree with you that there are unnecessary steps since we can use $\Delta=rs$ to derive the PT, but the same criticism can be made towards the proof (very complicated, btw) of PT using the Heron's formula. I have checked a good number a proofs of HF and,
 in all cases, I found that the proofs used tools that can be used to prove the PT quicker. I would like to know if you have the same opinion about such proofs of PT using HF. See this link:
https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/herons.shtml

Comment: Sorry, I would like to know your opinion about such proofs, I am pretty sure you will think they are unnecessary complicated as well.

Comment: I guess we can also say the same about the proof of PT using Ptolomy's theorem. If our intention is to show the central aspect of a result, then the complication is excused, I think.

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía: (Comments aren't for discussion; this may be my last. See my profile to contact me directly if you like.) The issue isn't "unnecessary complexity" but "unnecessary *steps*": having "$X\to Y$", you're offering $X\to Z\to Y$"; the Triangle Inequality itself tells us to prefer the former. :) ... Incidentally, [here's a trigonograph](https://i.imgur.com/C6BFHZw.png) showing $$a+b+c=2a\cos^2(B/2)+2b\cos^2(A/2)$$ W/cyclic counterparts, this gives a system that easily yields $\cos^2(C/2)=s(s-c)/ab$ w/o using areas or the LoC. An even-more-direct demonstration should be out there.

Comment: Please, justify the votes down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is valid, but, as I suggest in comments, it's a bit *unsatisfying*.

[OP's blog](https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2020/06/another-proof-for-two-well-known.html) proves the relation
$$\cos^2\tfrac12C=\frac{s(s-c)}{ab} \quad\left(=\frac{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)}{4ab} \right)\tag{1}$$
for a general $\triangle ABC$ using the fact that
$$sr=|\triangle ABC| = \tfrac12ab\sin C\tag{2}$$
where $r$ is the inradius. The issue here is that we "know" that the tangent segments from $C$ to the incircle have length $s-c$; for $C$ a right angle, these segments necessarily match the triangle's inradius, so that $(2)$ *immediately* reduces to
$$s(s-c)=\frac12ab \qquad\to\qquad a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag{2'}$$
without ever having to consider $(1)$ *or* the additional fact that $\cos 45^\circ=1/\sqrt{2}$.

We can attempt to salvage the situation by providing a more-direct proof of $(1)$.

---

Consider the following, which invokes the [Intersecting Secants Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_secants_theorem) for $C$ relative to the circle (ie, calculating the [power of $C$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) in two ways):

[image]

$$
|CB'||CA'| = |CP||CQ| \qquad\to\qquad 2a\cos\tfrac12C \cdot 2b\cos\tfrac12C = (a+b+c)(a+b-c) \tag{3}
$$

Dividing-through by $4ab$ gives us $(1)$. From here, we can consider the case with $C$ a right angle, introduce $\cos 45^\circ=1/\sqrt{2}$ by suitably Pythagorean-free means (see [OP's blog](https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2020/12/the-pythagorean-theorem-from.html)), and deduce $a^2+b^2=c^2$ as OP has shown. Done. $\square$

---

Now, one could (and should!) ask whether this approach to proving Pythagoras is *unsatisfying* in its own right. **Indeed, it is.**

Consider a version of the above figure, with a right angle at $C$ and with $A''$ the reflection of $A'$ across diameter $\overline{PQ}$:

[image]

Here, we see that we can use the [Intersecting Chords Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem) (ie, calculating the power of $A$ in two ways) to get, quite immediately,
$$|AA'||AA''| = |AP||AQ| \quad\to\quad b\cdot b = (c+a)(c-a) \quad\to\quad a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag{4}$$
So, there's *no need* to appeal to the value of $\cos45^\circ$ in order to reduce $2ab\cos^2\frac12C$ to $2ab$ in $(1)$ and prove Pythagoras.

Incidentally, it should perhaps be explicitly noted that, as Pythagorean proofs go, the figure above is itself overly-complicated. The elements of the proof are those contained in the circle alone. Here's a cleaner figure:

[image]

---

Perhaps there is some other approach to $(1)$ that doesn't just as easily, *independent* of $(1)$, lead to the Pythagorean Theorem, but I'll leave the search for it to the reader.

---

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía: BTW, [here's a direct proof](https://i.imgur.com/lQClAyo.png) of the sine half-angle formula, calculating the power of $C$ in two ways: $$|CB'||CA'|=|CP||CQ|\quad\to\quad 2a\sin\tfrac12C\cdot 2b\sin\tfrac12C=(c+(a-b))(c-(a-b))$$ After a few refinements, I'll be posting this and the cosine version to my [trigonography](https://trigonography.com) site.

Comment: There are several attractive proofs on your site. I am going to add a link to trigonography.

Comment: Hello, did you post your proofs in your site or somewhere else?

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía: *"did you post your proofs in your site or somewhere else?"* ... I seem to have lost track and forgotten about them.  (It's weird seeing a December 2020 date stamp; all of this seems so long ago to me. I blame the pandemic for warping my perception of time.) I'm not even sure what I was thinking any more. :)  When (if?) I get back into the proper mindset, I'll see about posting the proof(s) to my site. ... Thanks for the reminder! :)